# Insert values from table into two separate tables (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to populate a table by inserting the values from a temp table as well as a single value from another table.

I have the SQL down to insert values from my temp table into my real table except for one column, and that column is a foreign key to another table. Let me give some example sql.

```
INSERT INTO location(value1,value2,value3,foreign_key_value)
SELECT tmpValue1
       ,tmpValue2
       ,tmpValue3
       ,(foreign_key_value from a different table needs to be here)
FROM tmp_location
```

If the foreign_key_value was found in my tmp table I could do a join, but that is not where I need to get the information from. I was wondering if there is anyway to reference the column value from my table where the foreign key points to in my Select statement. Or if there is a better way to do this.

If you need more information or clarification let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into location(value1,value2,value3,foreign_key_value)
select tmpvalue1
       ,tmpvalue2
       ,tmpvalue3
       ,(select id from merchant where the_value = l.the_value)
from
    tmp_location l
```

Comment: Well the problem is that my tmp_location table does not have the value that I need in it. So I can't join based on that key. It is 3 seperate tables.

Comment: location table (Final Product) tmp_location (has all values needed except 1) merchant (contains the merchant_id which is needed on every row in "location table")

Comment: @Loeras You need to show how the are tables related. Show the output of `=> \d location` `=> \d tmp_location` and `=> \d merchant`

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to use \d but the only relation in this whole thing is between location and merchant, they are related on merchant_id. merchant_id is the primary key of merchant and a foreign key of location. tmp_location is just a table I am populating with data from a CSV and then using some of the values from it to populate location.

Comment: So basically, the location table needs to grab the value of the primary key in merchant to populate location.merchant_id, and it needs to happen within the same query because I am getting a "null value in merchant_id violates not null constraint" error without it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh wow, I was not aware that you could do sub selects within the column listing of a select. That is awesome, I am having a different issue now but it is based around some other schema issues. Thank you for your help!